# Password input css not taking effect

Tags: html, css, forms

I have all my inputs using the same css styles, yet my password input is very small compared to the text input.

[image]

On the [JS Fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/nhxhkLaz/), everything looks the same, it works just fine. The password input sizing issue appears on Chrome, Firefox, and IE both in development and production on my machine.

css:

```
.log-form input[type="text"],
.log-form input[type="date"],
.log-form input[type="datetime"],
.log-form input[type="email"],
.log-form input[type="number"],
.log-form input[type="password"]
.log-form input[type="search"],
.log-form input[type="time"],
.log-form input[type="url"],
.log-form textarea,
.log-form select 
{
    -webkit-transition: all 0.30s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.30s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: all 0.30s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 0.30s ease-in-out;
    outline: none;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    width: 100%;
    background: #fff;
    margin-bottom: 6px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    padding: 6px;
    color: #555;
    font: 95% Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.log-form input[type="text"]:focus,
.log-form input[type="date"]:focus,
.log-form input[type="datetime"]:focus,
.log-form input[type="email"]:focus,
.log-form input[type="number"]:focus,
.log-form input[type="password"]:focus,
.log-form input[type="search"]:focus,
.log-form input[type="time"]:focus,
.log-form input[type="url"]:focus,
.log-form textarea:focus,
.log-form select:focus
{
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px #43D1AF;
    padding: 6px;
    border: 1px solid #43D1AF;
}
```

Comment: Is your site live?

Comment: Yeah, you can see it live here. [Glipboard](http://www.glipboard.com/login)

Comment: Okay, so I didn't realize I neglected to add the div class of log-form around the input form in the JS Fiddle, when I did that it changed the size of the password field. JS Fiddle updated.

Comment: This CSS fixed the issue on my screen https://jsfiddle.net/7mksazzr/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You missed `,` after `[password]` and in html you are not using your `log-form` class.

**[fiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/nhxhkLaz/1/)**

```css
.log-form input[type="text"],
.log-form input[type="date"],
.log-form input[type="datetime"],
.log-form input[type="email"],
.log-form input[type="number"],
.log-form input[type="password"],

/* Added , which missed */

.log-form input[type="search"],
.log-form input[type="time"],
.log-form input[type="url"],
.log-form textarea,
.log-form select {
  -webkit-transition: all 0.30s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.30s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: all 0.30s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all 0.30s ease-in-out;
  outline: none;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 100%;
  background: #fff;
  margin-bottom: 6px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  padding: 6px;
  color: #555;
  font: 95% Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.log-form input[type="text"]:focus,
.log-form input[type="date"]:focus,
.log-form input[type="datetime"]:focus,
.log-form input[type="email"]:focus,
.log-form input[type="number"]:focus,
.log-form input[type="password"]:focus,
.log-form input[type="search"]:focus,
.log-form input[type="time"]:focus,
.log-form input[type="url"]:focus,
.log-form textarea:focus,
.log-form select:focus {
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px #43D1AF;
  padding: 6px;
  border: 1px solid #43D1AF;
}
```

```html
<div class="log-form">
  <!-- Added log-form -->
  <input type="text" name="text" placeholder="name"><br /><br />
  <input type="password" name="pwd" placeholder="password">
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Please add `,` after `[type="password"]` in the following selector chunk:

```
.log-form input[type="password"] .log-form input[type="search"],
```

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be a comma missing after[type=password].

Comment: Welcome to SO! There already is an answer that points out the problem you've mentioned. Instead of answering with a new answer that adds no new information its better to up vote that answer.